# Counting template instantiations with inline variables

Tags: global-variables, c++17

Let's say we want to count the number of a template instantiations for a certain template.

In C++17 I think I can do it like this:

```
static inline size_t my_template_count = 0;

template <typename T>
struct my_template {
  static inline char count_me = []{ my_template_count++; return 0; }();

  // mention count_me in all functions.
};
```

My questions are:
 - Will it work?
 - Can there be a race condition on the `total_count`?
   (Reading while DLL loading, something like that).

Update: as @n.m. correctly pointed out - I have to reference the variable.
It's ok for my usecase to include (void)count_me in all constructors, destructor, static methods etc. And if none of them are used, it's ok to ignore the instantiation.

Comment: The variable will never be instantiated unless you refer to it from instantiated code.

Comment: Thanks, that's true. I've updated the question.

Comment: If you reference it as you say in the question then it should work without a problem. If you have threads or other asynchroonous execution, make the counter atomic, otherwise there's no need to worry about race conditions.

Comment: And it turned out that I have an answer from SeanParent. Unfortunately, there is an issue. I'll post it even though I don't fully understand it.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question came up in a discussion with Sean Parent.
He said:

> Not thread safe because deferred dynamic initialization is not guaranteed to happen on the main thread [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization)